# C# Action delegate with custom class

Tags: c#

How does the Action delegate with custom classes work when i am not explicitly passing the input parameter type of the referenced method :

```
DirectMethodCall.PassMethod(x=>x.NoReturnOneParameterMethod(1));
public static void PassMethod(Action<NewClass> c)
{
   NewClass op = new NewClass();
   c(op);
}
```

Why do i need to pass the "op" to the Action delegate ?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx Action<T> requires you to pass an instance of the template type.

Comment: I vote to close, what is your question really ?

Comment: My question is regarding the working of how the Action delegate works when you pass not just  a method but an object that contains the method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As comments are a bit messy to post code examples, I'll continue here.

You are not repeating code, you're misunderstanding what you've actually coded. `public static void PassMethod(Action<NewClass> c)` means 
`PassMethod` requires, as a parameter, a method which executes on a `NewClass` object.

Maybe this makes it more clear:

```
void Main()
{
    //I am defining the implementation of a method which requires as integer as a parameter, but I don't actually invoke it, just define it.
    ExecuteMethod(i => Console.WriteLine(i));
}

public static void ExecuteMethod(Action<int> method)
{
    //I don't know what method does, all I know is that I am running it with the number 5.
    method(5);
}
```

`ExecuteMethod` Takes a method which requires an integer. It doesn't know what the method does. All it knows is that it requires an int, and it passes it the value `5`

The actual code is from the caller:

`i => Console.WriteLine(i)`

Here, `i` is set to 5, and so the result is 5 being printed to the console.

Answer (score 0):

Your `PassMethod` is expecting a delegate which accepts one parameter of type `NewClass` and it calls `NoReturnOneParameterMethod()` with parameter `1` and has a return type of `void`

`Action<T>` means it is a delegate that takes type `T` as its argument and has return type of `void`.

See: [MSDN Action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I know how delegates work and how is the Action working.My question was in this particular case how does the Action figured out the input parameter type of the reference method.In normally cases you would specify Action<int>

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is a reference type or a value type. It is `Action<T>` which means it's generic.

Comment: The signature of `PassMethod` already states it expects an `Action<NewClass>`. That's C#'s smart compiler for you. @ZohaibAmin

Comment: Can you elaborate on the behind the scenes of this smartness ?

Comment: because the `NoReturnOneParameterMethod` method expects an integer type.

Comment: in the delegate `x=>x.NoReturnOneParameterMethod(1)`, `x` is of type `NewClass` which has a method `NoReturnOneParameterMethod` which expects an `int`.

Comment: @Aniket which the OP neglected to post, so we have to infer it.

Comment: I actually am looking for nuts and bolts behind this as i did this code myself so i can interpret it but what i like to know  is WHY the "c" object is taking a parameter of type "NewClass" ?

Comment: @ZohaibAmin Because you told it to, the moment you added the parameter with the type Action<NewClass>. If the parameter were Action<int>, c would have to be passed an int

Comment: @Rob So i already specified it as Action<NewClass> , why do i have to instantiate a new object of the same type and pass it to "c".I know you would say this is how the language is working but is there any reason ?

Comment: Because your method "PassMethod" is saying 'Give me a method which requires 'NewClass', and I will supply it for you'. x is now referencing the value you pass in as 'c'. I am not sure what you mean what the reason for it is, this is the only way it's possible to implement. If PassMethod doesn't create a NewClass, what NewClass object is running 'NoReturnOneParameterMethod' ? `x` is pointing to the same object that `op` is.

Comment: @Rob It would make sense to not repeat the code it self as i would never be able to do c(NewClass2) as PassMethod already was expecting as you mentioned, the NewClass Action.
Its not logical to do int n=new int() and not assign and use it.

Comment: @ZohaibAmin You are not repeating code at all. I've posted an answer as comments are too restrictive to post snippets of code